# css submenu effecting the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Hello I was just creating a menu for my website using CSS. In the code I have placed the menu items in an unordered list as usual and placed a submenu inside one of the menu options. Now the problem is, when the sub menu becomes visible, The layout height increases as to match the height of the sub menu. If explanation is confusing, please see below image. Thank you.[After opening submenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh2cQ.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#services").click(function(){
$("#service").toggle();
});
});
```

```css
body {
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.layer {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.layer { position: absolute; }
  
.background {
  background: url("images/headerImage.jpg") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  bottom: -20px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 110%;
  left: -5%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index : -100;
}
.menuItems {
position : absolute;
width : 100%;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
background-color : black;
height : auto;
}
.menuItems ul {
list-style-type : none;
float : right;
margin-right : 2vw;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.menuItems ul li {
display : inline-block;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.menuItems ul li a {
color : white;
text-decoration : none;
display : block;
padding : 1vw;
margin : 0;
}
.menuItems ul li a:hover {
background-color : green;
text-decoration : none;
}
.menuItems ul li ul{
display : none;
overflow : hidden;
}
.menuItems ul li ul li{
display : block;
}
.menuItems ul li ul li a{
display : block;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
z-index : 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
 <div class="layer">
 <div class="background"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class = "menuItems">
<ul>
<li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Why us</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Accomodation</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Conference Hall</a></li>
<li><a href = "#" id = "services">Services</a>
<ul id = "service">
<li><a href = "#">Restaurant and Bar</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Travel</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Beauty care</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Health club & gym</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href = "#">Facilities</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Virtual tour</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh2cQ.jpg)

Comment: Your submenu should be positioned absolute to take it out of the document flow. Don't forget to make the parent positioned relative.

Comment: I assume you want a black dropdown submenu? If that's the case, you should position #service (the submenu) absolute to #services (which in turn need a position relative) and position and style the submenu accordingly.

Comment: First 'li' needs to be 'position: relative:' and sub 'li' needs to be 'position: absolute;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an absolute position on the submenu so the height of the nav won't be increase.

This should work :

```
.menuItems ul li {
  display : inline-block;
  padding : 0;
  margin : 0;
  /* Set position relative to the parent */
  position: relative;
}

.menuItems ul li ul{
  display : none;
  overflow : hidden;
  /* Set position absolute to the child */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%
  left: 0
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#services").click(function(){
$("#service").toggle();
});
});
```

```css
body {
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.layer {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.layer { position: absolute; }
  
.background {
  background: url("images/headerImage.jpg") no-repeat 50% 100%;
  bottom: -20px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  width: 110%;
  left: -5%;
  top: -5%;
  z-index : -100;
}
.menuItems {
position : absolute;
width : 100%;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
background-color : black;
height : auto;
}
.menuItems ul {
list-style-type : none;
float : right;
margin-right : 2vw;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
.menuItems ul li {
display : inline-block;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
position: relative;
}
.menuItems ul li a {
color : white;
text-decoration : none;
display : block;
padding : 1vw;
margin : 0;
}
.menuItems ul li a:hover {
background-color : green;
text-decoration : none;
}
.menuItems ul li ul{
display : none;
overflow : hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 100%;
}
.menuItems ul li ul li{
display : block;
}
.menuItems ul li ul li a{
display : block;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
z-index : 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
 <div class="layer">
 <div class="background"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class = "menuItems">
<ul>
<li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Why us</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Accomodation</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Conference Hall</a></li>
<li><a href = "#" id = "services">Services</a>
<ul id = "service">
<li><a href = "#">Restaurant and Bar</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Travel</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Beauty care</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Health club & gym</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href = "#">Facilities</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Virtual tour</a></li>
<li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

apply a fixed height for menu like below

```
    .menuItems {
position : absolute;
width : 100%;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
background-color : black;
height : 40px;
}
```

And adjust the other styles according to that

Answer (score 0):

For the submenu not to affect the menu, we usually use `position: absolute;` to move the element outside a layer. It may made a element could in a same place with other element. For that we will use `z-index: 99` (99 could be other number that larger than another element.)

Also, You will need to use left and top to align your element to specific place. e.g `left: 50px; top: 0px;`

[Here is my example](https://jsfiddle.net/L5297xdz/)